# Fourier series of rescaled cosine function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How would I find the Fourier series of $\cos\left(\, 5x/2\,\right) $ on
$\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$?

#### Progress

$$A_0={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(5x/2)dx={2\over 5\pi}$$

$$A_n = {1\over \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(5x/2) \cos(nx)dx={20 \cos(n\pi)\over 25-4n^2}$$

$$B_n = {1\over \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(5x/2)\sin(n x)dx=0$$

What will the final form of the answer look like?

Comment: I apologize. I updated the question.

Comment: Sorry. Forget that. I wanted to say b sub n and a naught.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that part I'm not quite understanding what a Fourier Series looks like. I updated my question as well.

Comment: Is the function $\cos(5x/2)$ or $\cos(5x)$?

Comment: cos(5x/2). Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: Your first integral is already wrong: $A_0$ is not zero. Note that in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, your function has two and a half cycles.

Comment: Ok. My mistake. Now I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your recent edit, your result $A_0 = 2/(5\pi)$ is correct. Also, you are correct that all of the $B_n$'s are zero because the integrand of
$$B_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(5x/2)\sin(nx) dx$$
is an even function times an odd function, hence odd. So that leaves the $A_n$ integral for $n \neq 0$. We have
$$A_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(5x/2)\cos(nx) dx$$
We may use the trig identity
$$\cos(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)\right)$$
and the fact that 
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\omega x) dx = \frac{2\sin(\omega\pi)}{\omega\pi}$$
to obtain
$$A_n = \frac{\sin((5/2 + n)\pi)}{(5/2 + n)\pi} + \frac{\sin((5/2 - n)\pi)}{(5/2 - n)\pi}$$
Note that for every integer $n$,
$$\sin((5/2 + n)\pi) = \sin((5/2 - n)\pi)$$
and that
$$\sin((5/2 + n)\pi) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
-1 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$$
In other words, $\sin((5/2 + n)\pi) = (-1)^n$. This allows us to simplify the expression as follows:
$$A_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\left( \frac{(-1)^n}{(5/2 + n)} + \frac{(-1)^n}{5/2 - n}\right) = \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{5(-1)^n}{25/4 - n^2} \right) = \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{20(-1)^n}{25 - 4n^2} \right)$$
which is about as simplified as one might hope for. This nearly matches your 
$$\frac{20\cos(n\pi)}{25-4n^2}$$
since $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$. One of us is off by a factor of $\pi$.

The final answer is 
$$A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin(nx) = \frac{2}{5\pi} + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{20(-1)^n}{25 - 4n^2} \right) \cos(nx)$$